Keycloak Admin Client - Unrecognized Field "userProfileMetadata" Error Despite Field Not Present in JSON
I am encountering a persistent issue when trying to create a user in Keycloak using the Keycloak Admin Client. Despite ensuring that the userProfileMetadata field is not present in the JSON payload, the Keycloak server responds with a 400 Bad Request error, indicating that the field is unrecognized. No matter whether  the userProfileMetadata field is in the User json or not, I keep getting the error!
I am using Spring boot 3.2.5 but my Keycloak server itself is 16.1.1
     <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <keycloak.version>22.0.3</keycloak.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <lombok.version>1.18.26</lombok.version>
    </properties>
<groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>24.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
        <version>25.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

Response from Keycloak: status=400, body=Unrecognized field "userProfileMetadata" (class org.keycloak.representations.idm.UserRepresentation), not marked as ignorable

I have added global configuration to ignore unknown properties.
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        return mapper;
    }
}

and the class to ignore unknown props:
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class FilteredUserRepresentation extends UserRepresentation {
    // No additional fields or methods needed
}

User creation methode:
    public ResponseEntity<String> createUserInKeycloak(String email, String password) {
    Keycloak keycloak = getKeycloak();

    UserRepresentation user = getUserRepresentation(email, password);

    log.debug("Creating user in Keycloak: {}", user);

    try {
        ObjectNode userNode = objectMapper.convertValue(user, ObjectNode.class);
        userNode.remove("userProfileMetadata");

        String userJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(userNode);
        log.info("Cleaned User JSON: {}", userJson);

        try (Response response = keycloak
                .realm(applicationProperties.getKeycloakAdminUser().getRealm())
                .users()
                .create(objectMapper.readValue(userJson, UserRepresentation.class))) {
            int status = response.getStatus();
            String responseBody = response.readEntity(String.class);
            log.info("Response from Keycloak: status={}, body={}", status, responseBody);

            if (status == HttpStatus.CREATED.value()) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>("User created successfully", HttpStatus.CREATED);
            } else {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(responseBody, HttpStatus.valueOf(status));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception while creating user in Keycloak", e);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("An error occurred: " + e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}


Had the same issue with keycloak-admin-client version 24.02. Upgrading to version 26.0.3 resolved the issue for me

For the record: Had the same issue with client lib version 23.07. Updating to 26.0.3 also resolved the problem. Doh...
